# MySQL AWS Record Locking Timeout not appearing in Slow Query Log?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, error-handling, amazon-rds, mysql-slow-query-log

**UPDATED BELOW 11.09.2023**

We have a sizeable database of roughly 200,000 lines of code complete with read-replica hosted on AWS. The problem is we're occasionally encountering a deadlock timeout error that I can't seem to track down. This error is "presented" as a `SAVEPOINT does not exist` error. I believe a sub-procedure is causing the timeout deadlock which is why the main procedure loses its savepoint (which is designed to rollback to in case of an error). Apparently a deadlock timeout of a subprocedure erases a savepoint...

We have slow logs turned on, and there's nothing in the logs indicating a record lock of any concerning time, or anything else. The whole thing is rather frustrating.

And of course this happened while I was asleep, so I couldn't query the `data_locks` or `data_lock_waits` tables. However it's so random, by the time we know it's happening, we almost never catch it.

Note our backend system does reuse open connections rather than closing them when everything is done. I believe the issue is related to the reuse of a connection - but in reality that should be fine since our system is designed to allow for 'core' procedure calls by the backend at any time with any connection.

Here's a snapshot of the main DB and the waits. I find it interesting the biggest wait are for the BIN_LOG, which synchronizes with the RR.

[image: Main Database]

Sadly, other than this, we have nothing to go on. As mentioned, slow logs have nothing useable in them; highest lock time value is: 00:00:00.000035

In many regards, it makes no sense. I know we have queries that lock longer than that. Perhaps the issue is the ones that lock aren't slow? Is there a setting I need to adjust?

Any advice on tracking this down would be appreciated.

---

So I've tried the Slow Log approach and no kidding; none of my locks times are more than 0.046564. Even with slow log set to 0... and yes, timeouts did take place... so I'm trying a different technique; an event monitoring system that watches sys.innodb_lock_waits and when there's records, I store the data for review. We're testing it out today. I'll let everyone know how it goes.

---

The deadlock error happened again, but my event monitor that runs every 5 seconds to check for lock waits returns nothing, which tells me the deadlock is returning immediately and not 'timing out'. Is this possible? I thought all deadlocks would time out...

SQL code is:

```
SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT
    (
      'waiting_trx_id',waiting_trx_id,
      'waiting_pid',waiting_pid,
      'waiting_query',waiting_query,
      'blocking_trx_id', blocking_trx_id,
      'blocking_pid', blocking_pid,
      'blocking_query', blocking_query
    ))
INTO
    json_results
FROM 
    sys.innodb_lock_waits;
```

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
AWS instance type? Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for a functioning Slow Query Log.

Comment: MySQL does not log queries for long lock time. It only logs queries for long _execution_ time, which is counted separately from lock time. To get all the queries, you would have to set `long_query_time=0` temporarily (be sure to restore that value to something nonzero after you get the information you need, or else your logs will grow too large).

Comment: @Floobinator   We will not get your LOCKOUT query into the Slow Query Log, but we can review settings to ensure you have a Slow Query Log available to those that = or exceed Long_Query_Time.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments; I updated the issue above. Wilson, I'll provide the details if my approach fails. Strange the deadlocked queries don't seem to show at all in the slow log...

Comment: "database of roughly 200,000 lines of code" -- A database has tables, which have "rows".  "Code" is not a DB metric.

Comment: How many _rows_ are being `UPDATEd`?  Let's see the `UPDATE` statement and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: (The "locks times" are essentially irrelevant in the slowlog.  The don't measure what you need them to.)

Comment: Is this the Primary?  Or a Replica?  If Replica, then some extra settings should be turned on; see [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog)

Comment: `SHOW ENGINE=INNODB STATUS;` to get the latest deadlock; pleas provide that section of the Status.

Comment: @BillKarwin - To get "all" queries on a Replica, several setting should be turned on.

Comment: Updated above. So the deadlocks are "random" as such whenever I manually query to catch them, they don't exist. I can't believe there's no logging ability in MySQL to report on these deadlocks... having to catch them in the moment is pretty ridiculous. Given the event approach isn't working, is there any other way to catch a deadlock and what caused it?

Comment: @Floobinator  For a record of ALL deadlocks, PARAMETER GROUP settings, A) innodb_deadlock_detect=1 ( or ON), )B innodb_print_all_deadlocks=1 (or ON) to record in your "Error Log".  SELECT @@log_output; is usually FILE.  SELECT @@log_error; for the filename where you will find your error log.  You may have to FLUSH LOGS; to ensure writes to logs have finished.  SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS only records 'latest deadlocks' - we have seen this report with a few or HUNDREDS of deadlocks - depending on recent activity and system workload.

Comment: @WilsonHauck if I enable what you propose, which log will they be written out to? Right now, I am monitoring mysql.slow_log. How would I select the results of deadlock_detect and print_all_deadlocks? My log_output is TABLE.

Comment: @Floobinator  SELECT @@log_error;  will reveal the destination of Error Log.  Select innodb_deadlock_detect; to determine current setting.  Select @@innodb_print_all_deadlocks'  to determine current setting.   Most AWS clients use Parameter Groups to set these variables.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I confirmed all deadlocks are being written out to the log files. Many of them are very large (250kb) Is there any way to get those deadlocks in a table, or is logging the only way?

Comment: Rather than getting them in a table - this URL and the 3 related references from the manual may help with preventing them.  Google search for MySQL deadlock prevention tutorial may provide useful articles for you. View profile for contact info.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html